# How to validate the draggable text moving around the boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have to validate the draggable text before touching the top, left, right and bottom. Before i have to alert the user with 1px margin border inside the box. It should not move after that 1px margin. How to achieve it using javascript or jquery?

https://jsfiddle.net/uf44m36j/1/

```
 $('.dragme').draggable({ containment: ".drag-parent" });
```

Comment: you have to write a function with the `.drag` event that finds the offset of the element to its parent.

Comment: on `stop` event you should verify the intersects with the parent. `position` property can help you.  https://jsfiddle.net/d345k0/phfyqp4j/

Comment: Could you do a sample

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand it, you want to notify user before the rectangle hits the border, don't you?
You can use drag event for this case, and identify the position in it.

Documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Here is the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/uf44m36j/2/

```js
 $('.dragme').draggable({ 
 containment: ".drag-parent",
 drag: function( event, ui ) {
  if (ui.position.top == 1) {
     //tell user the box almost hits the top
  }
  if (ui.position.left == 1) {
     //tell user the box almost hits the left
  }
 }
 });
```

```css
.dragme {
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        width: 12em;
        height: 8em;
        padding: 1em;
        font-family: "Montserrat", "Arial";
        background-color: #00C5CD;
        color: white;
    }
    
    
    .drag-parent {
    border: 0.1em solid #BA064E;
    width: 45em;
    height: 20em;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="drag-parent">
    <div class="dragme">Drag me!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: maulidan Before hitting i should alert the user with 1px margin border box.

Comment: @Parker I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean add the border to `drag-parent` or to `dragme` ?

Comment: @maulidan While i moving the text it should not touch the box border before that it should show 1px border solid margin around the box and stop there.